# Insert getusermedia to node.js and socket.io based chat engine

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket, webrtc

I have this code running in

**Client side:**

```
$(function(){
  var iosocket = io.connect();
  iosocket.on('connect', function () {
    $('#incomingChatMessages').append($('<li>Connected</li>'));
    iosocket.on('message', function(message) {
      $('#incomingChatMessages').append($('<li></li>').text(message));
    });
    iosocket.on('disconnect', function() {
      $('#incomingChatMessages').append('<li>Disconnected</li>');
    });
  });
  $('#outgoingChatMessage').keypress(function(event) {
    if(event.which == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      iosocket.send($('#outgoingChatMessage').val());
      $('#incomingChatMessages').append($('<li></li>').text($('#outgoingChatMessage').val()));
      $('#outgoingChatMessage').val('');
    }
  });
});
```

**Server Side**

```
var fs = require('fs'), http = require('http'), socketio = require('socket.io');
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-type': 'text/html'});
  res.end(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/index.html'));
}).listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('Listening at: localhost');
});

socketio.listen(server).on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('message', function (msg) {
    console.log('Message Received: ', msg);
    socket.broadcast.emit('message', msg);
  });
});
```

**Question** :
How can I include the getUserMedia and other WEBRTC API's to create a simple video application ?

Comment: maybe googling will get you started

Comment: @supernova I googled, and found out tutorials with OpenTOK API but I want to use WEBRTC

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at, or found, an opensource code set named [webrtc.io](https://github.com/webRTC/). If you look at the example code (in the webrtc.io-demo project), you will find a really good example of how to use the getusermedia and peerconnection API's. This code does implement node.js but websocket.io instead of socket.io. I do not know that much about either, so I am not sure if there exists any compatibility between them.